# Fastest way to send 20 bytes of data over C-based bluetooth low energy module

Tags: c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

This is more of a C programming question than a Bluetooth question.

I have a custom 128-bit UUID service containing an attribute with read/notify properties. The notify property is configured to send 20 bytes worth of data per notify packet. Currently, I am populating an array of 8-bit unsigned integers with 20 members using a `for` loop then sending it over the Bluetooth link.

This process takes about 1s which is far too slow (I am trying to maximize throughput). Is there a better way of moving 20 bytes other than in an array?  I was able to achieve about 9k bit/s when I used just one `uint64_t` to hold the data but that only amounts to 8 bytes. My goal is to populate the full 20 byte capacity of the notify charateristic with the same speed.

My notify method is as follows: This fills in the value (`val[]`) to notify the client.  It also sends a kernal message to the profile which then initiates a notification.

```
void app_sample128_set_char2_val(uint8_t* value)//(uint64_t value)
{   
    // Allocate the message
    struct sample128_upd_char2_req * req = KE_MSG_ALLOC(SAMPLE128_UPD_CHAR2_REQ, TASK_SAMPLE128, TASK_APP, sample128_upd_char2_req);

    // Fill in the parameter structure
    req->conhdl = app_env.conhdl;
    for (int x=0; x<20; x++)
    {
        req->val[x] = value[x];
    }
    ke_msg_send(req);   
}
```

The characteristic update handler function is as follows: This function calls `prf_server_send_event()` which is responsible for sending notifications.

```
static int sample128_upd_char2_req_handler(ke_msg_id_t const msgid,
                                struct sample128_upd_char2_req const *param,
                                ke_task_id_t const dest_id,
                                ke_task_id_t const src_id)
{
    uint8_t status = PRF_ERR_OK;

    // Check provided values
    if(param->conhdl == gapc_get_conhdl(sample128_env.con_info.conidx))
    {
        // Update value in DB
        attmdb_att_set_value(sample128_env.sample128_shdl + SAMPLE128_2_IDX_VAL,
                             20, (uint8_t *)&param->val);
                            //maximum data value size for a notification attribute  = 20 bytes

    if((sample128_env.feature & PRF_CLI_START_NTF))
        // Send notification through GATT
        prf_server_send_event((prf_env_struct *)&sample128_env, false, sample128_env.sample128_shdl + SAMPLE128_2_IDX_VAL);
    }
    else
    {
        status = PRF_ERR_INVALID_PARAM;
    }

    if (status != PRF_ERR_OK)
    {
        sample128_upd_char2_cfm_send(status);
    }

    return (KE_MSG_CONSUMED);
}
```

Comment: What chip are you using? what library are you using to access bluetooth? what does the notify method look like? Can we see osme code?

Comment: I am using the Dialog Semiconductor DA14580 BLE chip based on the ARM Cortex M0 processor with the Riviera Waves BLE solution.

Comment: I was able to solve this problem by passing a structure containing 2 unsigned 64-bit integers and one unsigned 32-bit integer.